# Firefox: migrate Adblock filters between machines

Tags: firefox

I have several good filters for Adblock Plus. How to move the filter preferences to Firefox on other machine?

Comment: If there aren't many filters, you could just click `edit` on the filters you want, paste them to pastebin.com or any site you want and add them in the other machine. Alternatively, depending on your adblock plus version, you can create a backup file of your filters by right clicking on the adblock plus icon, then on `filter preferences`, selecting the `custom filters` tab, then clicking on `backup and restore` and creating a new backup file, uploading it somewhere and downloading on the new machine. Tell me if there is that option on your adblock, if there is I'll add an answer.

Comment: Yes, I have `Backup and Restore` buttons on both Firefoxes. Plz, add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or click the red Adblock Plus icon and then `Filter Options` to open the filters window. Now you can do one of the following:

1. If you have only a few filters.

   Select the filter you want to backup and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or click on the `Actions` button and then `Show/Hide Filter`. Then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy. Paste it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or any other website or to a text file and save it on a flash drive or something. Create a new filter on the other computer and simply paste what you backed up on pastebin.
2. If you have a lot of filters.

   In that same filters window, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or go to `Backup and Restore > Create new backup` to create a backup copy, save it on a flash drive, upload it whatever, and on the new computer, on that same filter window, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or `Backup and Restore > Load file` to select a backup file - load the file you saved and that will load your previous filters. Just make sure you do this both under the regular `Filters` tab and under the `Custom filters` tab.